# Solve for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: functions

we have to find all the solutions of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, given that,

$f(x)\cdot g(x) = f(x) + g(x)$

$(f(x) - 1 )\cdot( g(x) - 1 ) = 1$

I have found out 2 solutions so far, $f(x)= g(x) = 2$, and $f(x) = \sec^2(x)$ , $g(x) = \csc^2(x)$, (and vice versa)

Comment: You have two unknowns $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, but the second condition leads to the first one. $(f(x)-1)(g(x)-1) = f(x)g(x)-f(x)-g(x)+1 = 1$ anyways

Comment: your second equation is same as first one. So there are many solutions.

Comment: oh I see, thanks for pointing out,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two equations you gave are actually just forms of the same information, since $1= ( f-1)(g-1) = fg - f -g + 1 .$ These are infinitely many solutions  to this for general functions $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, or even if we assume stronger conditions of the functions like continuity, differentiability etc.

For any function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ where $f(x)\neq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ , we can pair it with $\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{1}{ f(x) -1} +1 $ to form a solution.